# Convert 1bpp bitmap to image in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm reading a raw image from the network. This image is being sent from some good old hardware.

These are the things I know about the image:

- Height and width
- Total size (in bytes)
- 1-bit per pixel (1bpp black and white)
- There's no header info or anything like that

I'm trying to convert this image to a bitmap to display in an ImageView (and also store as a file).

I haven't been able to find anything in the Android APIs that directly supports doing this kind of transformation. Do I have to roll my own converter or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the API supports this directly. However, you may not have to roll your own, since the work seems to have been done before: take a look at this project:

https://github.com/acdevs/1bpp-monochrome-android